# MVVM view models to one view

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, mvvm, blazor

I am using MVVM here. I have one model `Patient.cs` and 3 view models `ViewModel1`, `ViewModel2`, `ViewModel3`. I now have to convert 3 view models into one model.

Can someone please let me know the best way to do it. Below is my code:

**ViewModel1.cs**

```
    public class ViewModel1 {
        [Required]
        public string? YearOfBirth { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string? DriversLicenseId { get; set; }
        
    }
```

**ViewModel2.cs**

```
    public class ViewModel2
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(16, ErrorMessage = "First name should be 16 character or less.")]
        public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    
        [Required]
        [StringLength(16, ErrorMessage = "Last name should be 16 character or less.")]
        public string? LastName { get; set; }
    
        [Required]
        public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; } 
        
    }
```

**ViewModel3.cs**

```
public class ViewModel3
    {
        [Required]
        public string? Address1 { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string? City { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string? State { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string? ZipCode { get; set; }    
    
        
    }
```

Model **Patient.cs**

```
    public class Patient 
    {
       public string? FirstName { get; set; }
       public string? LastName { get; set; }
       public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
       public Gender? Gender { get; set; }
       public string? YearOfBirth { get; set; }
       public string? DriversLicenseId { get; set; }
       public string? Address1 { get; set; }
       public string? City { get; set; }
       public string? State { get; set; }
       public string? ZipCode { get; set; } 
       public string? PaymentType { get; set; }
     }
```

I'm looking for some way to convert all the three view models to Patient.cs

Thanks.

Comment: are you using the three view models elsewhere?

Comment: I've seen this before, do not delete & repost.

Comment: like I posted, I don't know how to and need a way to merge/bind data from viewmodels to model together

Answer (score 0):

As I see it you would need to do this kind of business explicitly. If it is important for you to maintain the fragmentation of the Model fields across 3 separate view models, then if it was me I would create a type of Super View Model which contained instances of the 3 ViewModel1,2,3 and bind your view Context to an instance of that Super ViewModel instead. You would bind your fields in your view to their respective properties, prefixing the properties with `ViewModel1.`, `ViewModel2` or `ViewModel3` e.g. bind your First Name text field to the property `ViewModel1.FirstName` You can then create an instance of the Patient model class and set the fields explicitly (see the `SavePatientRecord` procedure) Something like the following ...

```
public class SuperViewModel 
{
   private ViewModel1 _viewModel1;
   private ViewModel2 _viewModel2;
   private ViewModel3 _viewModel3;
   public ViewModel1 ViewModel1
   {
       get
       {
           return _viewModel1;
       }
       set
       {
           _viewModel1 = value;
       }
   }

   public ViewModel2 ViewModel2
   {
       get
       {
           return _viewModel2;
       }
       set
       {
           _viewModel2 = value;
       }
   }
   
   public ViewModel3 ViewModel3
   {
       get
       {
           return _viewModel3;
       }
       set
       {
           _viewModel3 = value;
       }
   }
  

   public SuperViewModel()
   {
       _viewModel1 = new ViewModel1();
       _viewModel2 = new ViewModel2();
       _viewModel3 = new ViewModel3();
   }

   public ICommand SavePatientRecord()
   {
       Patient patient = new Patient();

       patient.YearOfBirth = ViewModel1.YearOfBirth;
       patient.DrivesLicenceId = ViewModel1.DrivesLicenceId;
       
       patient.FirstName = ViewModel2.FirstName;
       patient.LastName = ViewModel2.LastName;
       patient.DateOfBirth = ViewModel2.DateOfBirth;

       patient.Address1 = ViewModel3.Address1;
       patient.City = ViewModel3.City;
       //
       // etc.
       // etc.
       //
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't use to repeat the `variables`

**Patient.cs**

```
public class Patient 
{
   // Constructor
   public Patient()
   {
       _viewModel1 = new ViewModel1();
       _viewModel2 = new ViewModel2();
       _viewModel3 = new ViewModel3();
   }
   public ViewModel1 _viewModel1 { get; set; }
   public ViewModel2 _viewModel2 { get; set; }
   public ViewModel3 _viewModel3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Now you have ViewModels in your Application Layer. Not good.